# Configure routing through vlans + static routing

Tags: routing, vlan, static-routes

I have problem configuring my network. Between switches I created vlans: 5,6,9 and 10. Vlan 9 is the native vlan. PC1 is in vlan 5 and PC0 is in vlan 6. I configured R1 that is possible to communicate through different vlans (ping from PC0 to PC1 works fine). Now I want to ping R3 se0/2 interface from PC1 but I have no response. Here are my configuration files:

**SWITCH S1:**

```
Current configuration : 942 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S1
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet3/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet4/1
!
interface FastEthernet5/1
!
interface FastEthernet6/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet7/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet8/1
!
interface FastEthernet9/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 99
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
end
```

**SWITCH S2:**

```
Current configuration : 830 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S2
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet3/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet4/1
!
interface FastEthernet5/1
!
interface FastEthernet6/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet7/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet8/1
 switchport access vlan 6
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet9/1
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
end
```

**SWITCH S3:**

```
Current configuration : 830 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S3
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
!
interface FastEthernet3/1
!
interface FastEthernet4/1
!
interface FastEthernet5/1
!
interface FastEthernet6/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet7/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet8/1
 switchport access vlan 5
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet9/1
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
end
```

**ROUTER R1** :

```
Current configuration : 1039 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.5
 encapsulation dot1Q 5
 ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.6
 encapsulation dot1Q 6
 ip address 192.168.6.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.9
 encapsulation dot1Q 9
 ip address 192.168.9.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet5/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.2 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**ROUTER R2** :

```
Current configuration : 649 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 ip address 172.16.1.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet5/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**ROUTER R3** :

```
Current configuration : 690 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0
 clock rate 64000
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet5/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.16.1.2 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**ROUTIG TABLES, R1:**

```
R1#sh ip route 
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 192.168.10.2 to network 0.0.0.0

C    192.168.5.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.5
C    192.168.6.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.6
C    192.168.9.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.9
C    192.168.10.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.10
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 192.168.10.2
```

**ROUTIG TABLES, R2:**

```
R2#sh ip ro
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     172.16.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.16.1.0 is directly connected, Serial2/0
C    192.168.10.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

**ROUTIG TABLES, R3:**

```
R3#sh ip route 
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 172.16.1.2 to network 0.0.0.0

     172.16.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.16.1.0 is directly connected, Serial2/0
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.16.1.2
```

My topology: http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/screen6pn_xwqenpw.png

**How can I change my network configuration to be able to ping from PC0/PC1 to 172.16.1.2 or 172.16.1.1 ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add comments, but as far as I can see, you don't have route from PC0/PC1 to reach R3.

You can reach from PC0 to PC1 because they are somewhat connected into the same network, even if onto different VLANs.  You will need to construct a routing table, throughout your network so your PCs may reach R2/R3.

The basic route you need to add is pointing 172.16.1.0/24 to the internal IP Address of R2.